# C#: Save a Class Type into a Variable?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to save some UserControl-Infos into a List like this:

```
List<UserControlDetails> myList;
public UserControlDetails 
{
    string Description { get; set; }
    Type UserControlType { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I display this List in a ListView, I want to be able to start my UserControl e.g. via the SelectedItem Property like

```
 //SelectedItem.UserControlType = MyMainViewModel;
 var tmp = new SelectedItem.UserControlType(); //This will return a new instance of MainViewModel
```

Any ideas how to do this? Or other ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers

EDIT: Thanks a bunch for the responses. Another question: How do you save the type of a "MaiNViewModel" into a type variable? I get a "Class name is not valid" error

EDIT2: Got it, it's typeof(). I'll now try out the methods and report back as soon as possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want:

```
object tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(SelectedItem.UserControlType);
```

If that's always going to be a descendant of some common type (e.g. `UserControl`) then you can cast it:

```
Type type = SelectedItem.UserControlType;
UserControl tmp = (UserControl) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
// You can now use the members of UserControl on tmp.
```

This assumes there's a public parameterless constructor though, as that's what [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) calls.

Answer (score 4):

The dirty and easy way : [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).
IMHO, you should try with a [factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954600.aspx).

Comment: +1 for mentioning factories. If it's only used to create instances, the type shouldn't be exposed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(SelectedItem.UserControlType);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming you want to use the default constructor
object control = Activator.CreateInstance(SelectedItem.UserControlType);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new instance from type information using Activator.CreateInstance(Type t).